# Swift - UITableView set separator style

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

How do i set the Separator Style of my UITableView in Swift? I want to get rid of the separator so that there is no grey line between the cells in my table view. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.Below is what I have already tried.

I have found this method in objective-C

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]
```

I tried my best to translate this to swift with

```
self.tableView.setSeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

But this presents the error

```
'(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'setSeparatorStyle'
```

In the apple documentation it gives these declarations in objective-C

```
typedef enum : NSInteger  {


UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone ,
   UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine ,
   UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched 
} UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle;
```

So I tried again to translate it to Swift using

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, setSeparatorStyle style: NSInteger) -> NSInteger {
    return UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone
}
```

But this just throws up more errors, "Use of unresolved identifier 'UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To explain why you can't call `setSeparatorStyle` in Swift, I need to explain where that method comes from in Objective-C. If you search for it in the header (`UITableView.h`) you won't find it. The only thing declared is this:

```
@property (nonatomic) UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle separatorStyle;
```

`setSeparatorStyle` is the setter automatically generated for a property in Objective-C. Let's say you declare a property in Objective-C, like this:

```
@interface SomeClass: NSObject

@property (nonatomic) id someProperty;

@end
```

Objective-C will automatically generate a setter and getter method for that property, with the getter being the name of the property, and the setter being the name with `set` prefixed.

So you can call the getter like this:

`[object someProperty]`

And you can set the property like this:
`[object setSomeProperty:newValue]`

Now, that's all great, but there's a shorter way to call the setter and getter, namely **dot syntax**, which looks like this:

`object.someProperty = newValue; // setter`

And the getter:

`object.someProperty // getter`

Now in Swift, this *implicit* generation of a setter in this `setSomeProperty` way doesn't exist anymore. It had always been a weird quirk of Objective-C, so Swift introduces a unified way to set and get properties. **In Swift, there's only one way to set and get properties and it's using dot syntax**, which is identical to the dot syntax in Objective-C.

So to actually answer your question, you need to remove the `set` part in `setSeparatorStyle`, and this would be your new code:

```
self.tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
```

Usually you don't have to write `self`, Swift is smart enough to realize you want to use `self.tableView` if there's only one variable named `tableView` in scope, so you can write

```
tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
```

And Swift is even smart enough to realize that what comes after the assignment operator (the equals sign, `=`) is probably a separator style, so you can just write `.none`.

```
tableview.separatorStyle = .none
```

Comment: Great post! In Swift4 .None has been renamed to .none

Answer (score 8):

For those who are looking for Swift 2 and 3 notation :

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
```

Answer (score 7):

I used :

```
tableview.separatorStyle = .None
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 5

```
tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
```

Answer (score 3):

Look under the:

`Attributes inspector > table view > separator`
This should help you change the separator style or remove it completely

Comment: Thanks this is also a valid solution

Answer (score 2):

***Swift 5***

We can add UITableView set separator style below.

```
@IBOutlet weak private var listingTableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            listingTableView.delegate = self
            listingTableView.dataSource = self
            listingTableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine **OR** .none
            listingTableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
            listingTableView.separatorColor = UIColor(hex: "E6E6E6")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

tableView.separatorStyle = .none
tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine

Comment: This answer doesn't provide any explanation nor does it improve in any way on the existing answers. It's always best to include an explanation and not just code.