# How do you make the lines of a UITableView transparent?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I want to make it so that the lines of UITableView's cells are transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method do this

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, I just got an error

Comment: Use unresolved identifier UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone

Comment: That is strange, I hope you are using that line of code correctly i.e. in this method   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I'm programming in Swift. It looks like you're writing in Obj C

Comment: Then you should follow this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760212/swift-uitableview-set-separator-style)

Comment: Thanks you so much! I would like your post but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: No problem !! But you should always first search about your problem and look for possible duplicates .

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called each time a cell is shown on screen; you really don't need to set the property that often; once should do it. `viewDidLoad` or the setter for `tableView` would be a much better place as the separator style will only be set once.